# how can i get the value from datapicker using angular day, month, and year separate

Tags: datepicker, angular6

am using angular 6 datepicker i need to get the date selected, separate day and month and year

```
this.search_form.controls["startDate"].value

  console.log("full date",this.search_form.controls["startDate"].value);
    console.log("day",this.search_form.controls["startDate"].value.date().toString());
    console.log("month+1",this.search_form.controls["startDate"].value.month().toString()+1);
    console.log("year",this.search_form.controls["startDate"].value.year().toString());
```

I need to get  day=3 month=4 year=2019 also get the date as 03/4/2019

Answer (score 0):

Use   for separate date ,month n year
See the example below:-

Overview for datepicker
The datepicker allows users to enter a date either through text input, or by choosing a date from the calendar. It is made up of several components and directives that work together

Basic Datepicker:-
 Connecting a datepicker to an input
A datepicker is composed of a text input and a calendar pop-up, connected via the matDatepicker property on the text input.

If you want to set the start date you have to use the 'startAt' property of the .

To select month and year you have to use monthSelected and yearSelected property of the